# KVC release objs using valueForKeyPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, key-value-coding, kvc

I have a lot of objects named `_Obj_1`, `_Obj_2`, etc...
And I want to release all.

I'm using KVC. In particular to release all, i use:

```
MyClass *obj = nil;
for ( int i=1 ; i<=14; i++ ) {
  obj = [self valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_Obj_%d", i]];
  [obj release];
}
```

clang analyzer tell me for `[obj release];`

> Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not
>   owned at this point by the caller?

How can I fix it?

It's not an ARC project.

Comment: Why are you using this for releasing that poor object? This really is a hackish antipattern.

Comment: well, thanks. Now, with comments/response/negative vote i know that is a stupid way to release obj with kvc. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed very easily

**If you don't own the object (you didn't call retain), don't release it!**

Instead of having lots of variables with the same name, use an array to hold the objects. Then the releasing will be only the release of an array.

Comment: Agreed. Clang's warning is correct here. This is a very dangerous use of `valueForKeyPath:`.